# WordPress how to line up images in three columns (modulo)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have trouble to get images from a wordpress page in 3 columns.

At the moment my function for this counts and puts out every 3 images behind each other in a column but should put out every 3 images row after row. Has anybody an idea to reach this?

For example, if I have 8 images I get now something like in the picture:

[image]

Here is my actual code...

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Team
*/


/**
 * Header einbinden
 */
get_header(); ?>


    <!-- Seiteninhalt dynamisch -->
    <div id="primary" class="content-area wrapper">
        <div id="content" class="site-content content" role="main">

        <div class="post row">


        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-md-12 dg_para dg_list">
                <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => null,
                'post_parent' => $post->ID
            );

            $i = 0;
            $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                if ( $attachments ) {
                    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                        if($i %3 == 0){
                        echo '</div><div class="col-md-4 dg_para">';
                        echo '<figure>';
                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array(350,160), false, array( 'class' => 'dg_teamimg' ) );
                            echo '<figcaption><span class="dg_teamimgtext">';
                            echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
                            echo '</span></figcaption></figure>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<figure>';
                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array(350,160), false, array( 'class' => 'dg_teamimg' ) );
                            echo '<figcaption><span class="dg_teamimgtext">';
                            echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
                            echo '</span></figcaption></figure>';
                    }
                    $i++;
                    }
                }

            endwhile; endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <!-- Seiteninhalt dynamisch Ende -->
</div><!-- #container -->





<?php
 /**
  * Footer einbinden
  */
  get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following for loop:

```
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    if($i %3 == 0){
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }

    echo '<div class="col-md-4 dg_para">';
    echo '<figure>';
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array(350,160), false, array( 'class' => 'dg_teamimg' ) );
    echo '<figcaption><span class="dg_teamimgtext">';
    echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
    echo '</span></figcaption></figure>';
    echo '</div>';

    $i++;
    if($i %3 == 0 || count($attachments) == $i){
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

If this is the first of three md-4 columns, a row will be echoed. After that the md-4 divs are echoed with the figures. After `$i` has been increased by 1, there is a check if the next loop will open a row or if this was the last loop. If so, the row div is closed.